# byte array to Hindi Unicode Value

Tags: java, string, unicode, hindi

Hi I have a small function which prints byte to Hindi which is stored as Unicode. My function is like

```
public static void byteArrayToPrintableHindi(byte[] iData) {

    String value = "";
    String unicode = "\\u";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < iData.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {

            value = value.concat(unicode.concat(String.format("%02X", iData[i])));
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", iData[i]));
        } else {
            value = value.concat(String.format("%02X", iData[i]));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("value = "+value);
    System.out.println("\u091A\u0941\u0921\u093C\u093E\u092E\u0923\u093F");

}
```

and the output is

```
value = \u091A\u0941\u0921\u093C\u093E\u092E\u0923\u093F
चुड़ामणि
```

I am expecting the value to print

```
चुड़ामणि
```

I don't know why it is not printing the desired output.

Answer (score 4):

You're misunderstanding how `\uXXXX` escape codes work. When the Java compiler reads your source code, it interprets those escape codes and translates them to Unicode characters. You cannot at runtime build a string that consists of `\uXXXX` codes and expect Java to automatically translate that into Unicode characters - that's not how it works. It only works with literal `\uXXXX` codes in your source code.

You can simply do this:

```
public static void byteArrayToPrintableHindi(byte[] iData) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String value = new String(iData, "UTF-16");

    System.out.println("value = "+value);
    System.out.println("\u091A\u0941\u0921\u093C\u093E\u092E\u0923\u093F");
}
```

assuming that the data is UTF-16-encoded.